# run all selenium ruby webdriver scripts at a time.

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

Currently, I'm running each my Selenium Ruby Webdriver script (*.rb) on Ruby command prompt window with the syntax, ex: ruby test.rb. It works well.

However, I also have some other scripts and now I want to run all scripts once instead of calling ruby test1.rb, then wait for this script done, then continue to run: ruby test2.rb.....then, ruby test3.rb.....

Anybody please guide me a way to run all scripts I created at a time? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the rake `gem`, for this you need to create a file named `rakefile.rb`, and paste the below content:

```
task :default do
    FileList['file*.rb'].each { |file| ruby file }
end
```

Now call `rake` in your terminal, you should be good.

Comment: many thanks for your clear guide, However it not work for me yet. Below are things I have done: I installed rake gem (by syntax: gem install rake) successfully, then I created a file named "rakefile.rb" with content exactly as your suggestion, then just call rake as guided, but system does nothing, no script is run (but should be run).

I also tried to run with syntax: ruby rakefile.rb, but an error message displayed:

rakefile.rb:1:in `<main>': undefined method `task' for main:Object (NoMethodError). 
Could you please enlighten up me more ? thanks again.

Comment: @battleship the above code snippet expects that your scripts name should be something like file1.rb file2.rb file3.rb ... the rakefile.rb and other scripts needs to be in the same folder; Now type `rake` in the terminal; then everything should work fine. You can also have different file names, then you should also rename the `FileList['file*.rb']` accordingly

Comment: could you please also guide me a way to export the content/logs of each script (displayed on the terminal when executing a script) to text files and displays the list of failed scripts in a text file ? because I want system to run all scripts I have, then displays a report with script failed. I think this maybe takes your time much, so just give me a clue (if possible). Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

What about making a feature file and running the entire feature?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a ruby file like this:

```
require './Test1.rb'
require './Test2.rb'
```

Run it and see the result